# PHP: Include one class functions to another

Tags: php

I have large class `foo`, that I want to split to two separate classes (and files);

My class `foo` uses contruct function and noumerous `$this` references.

I need a second class `bar` to be an extension for original `foo` class, so I could still use contruction with additional parameter if to include `bar` class;

```
$includeBar = true;
$foo = new foo($config, $includeBar);
```

I've tried putting it this way:

```
Class bar extends foo {

   public function barFunction(){
      //some function of bar
   }
}


Class foo {

   public function __construct($config, $includeBar = true) {
      if ($includeBar) {
         include_once 'bar.php';
      }
   }

}
```

But when I call:

```
$foo = new foo($config, true);
$foo->barFunction();
```

It fails, saying

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method foo::barFunction()`

What am I doing wrong? pls help, got stuck

Comment: In which page are you calling `$foo = new foo($config, true);` ? show us the includes from it.

Comment: What is the use case for this? Why not instead of passing `$includeBar` conditionally instantiate an instance of `bar` rather than `foo` when needed?

Comment: @aendeerei thats the whole script. I just initialize `foo` class and expect functions from `bar` class to be available as well as functions from `foo`;

Comment: @smashed-potatoes use case is simple - `bar` class is large collection of api functions that just fetch some info. `foo` class is small collection of more sofisticated functions, some of which should use `bar` functions. I want to separate those functions in two different files and two different classes.

Comment: it is simply the other way round. foo should extend bar. And then, when instanciating the class, call the extending one (foo). Then there's no need for a param `$includeBar `

Comment: @Jeff ! yes it worked. Im so dummy :) Pls post an answer

Comment: In general, if you include a file inside a function, the code found in the file is callable only inside the function, not outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

It should be the other way round.
Bar is your base class, that contains all the methods that every sub class also needs. Foo is the extention, the extras, so Foo extends Bar.

```
<?php 

// file bar.php
Class Bar {
    public function __construct($config) {
         $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function barFunction() {
        echo "I'm everybody ".$this->config['msg'];
    }
}

// file foo.php
require_once('bar.php');

Class Foo extends Bar {
    public function fooOnly() {
        echo "I'm foo ".$this->config['msg'];
    }   
}


// consuming file index.php
include('foo.php');
$config = array('msg'=>'and I need coffee');
$foo = new foo($config);
$foo->barFunction();  // we can call this, because foo extends bar

// this won't work:
$bar = new Bar($config);
$bar->fooOnly();

// but this:
$bar->barFunction();
$foo->fooOnly();
```

(all the includes/requires can be omitted when using a proper autoloader!)

Answer (score 0):

If you want reuse class methods or separate class method implementation I think you can use [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) and then you can use keyword `use` to require functions to your class.

For example:

```
<?php
class Base {
    public function sayHello() {
        echo 'Hello ';
    }
}

trait SayWorld {
    public function sayHello() {
        parent::sayHello();
        echo 'World!';
    }
}

class MyHelloWorld extends Base {
    use SayWorld;
}

$o = new MyHelloWorld();
$o->sayHello();
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Hello World!
```